# parameterized routing not accepting the dot as parameter in web api routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using the parameterized routing for my web api calling. it is working fine for all special characters other than dot.
code which I tried

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route(@"TestMethod/{strvalue:regex((?s).*)}")]
 public IHttpActionResult TestMethod(string strvalue)
    {
        try
        {
           // logic
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error details:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

when I pass the parameter value dot(.) it is not accepting the request. getting the response as

```
 Request URL
 http://localhost:64515/TestMethod/.

 Response: 
 {
"Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}
```

Expected result: even if i pass any charactor like #,.%$@#&* that request should be accept

Answer (score 0):

Following code in your web.config should fix your issue:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: try this <add name="Nancy" path="api" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" allowPathInfo="true"

Comment: <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
 <add name="Nancy" path="api" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" allowPathInfo="true"></add> 
  </handlers>       not working